# what is the purpose of using 2 .then in http requests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Please explain me the following code snippet.. I'm trying to send a PUT request to edit single region ...
I want to get explained how the Success action is fired with 2 .then s.....and why to use 2 .then s?

```
const editRegion = createLogic({
  type: types.EDIT_REGION,
  latest: true,
  debounce: 1000,

  process({ MockHTTPClient, getState, action }, dispatch, done) {
    let HTTPClient;
    if (MockHTTPClient) {
      HTTPClient = MockHTTPClient;
    } else {
      HTTPClient = API;
    }

    let object = action.payload;

    HTTPClient.Put(endPoints.EDIT_REGIONS, object)
      .then(resp => resp.data)
      .then(data => dispatch(actions.editRegionSuccess(data)))

      .catch(err => {
        var errorMessage;
        if (err.response && err.response.status == 400) {
          errorMessage = err.response && err.response.data.errormessage;
        }
        dispatch(
          actions.editRegionFailed({
            title: "Error!",
            message: err
          })
        );
      })
      .then(() => done());
  }
});
```

Comment: Typically it's because extracting the response payload is *also* returning a promise, i.e. `.then(response => response.json())`. If you don't need to use a promise to get the data you need though you won't really need the second thenable.

Comment: This is a promise chaining pattern

Comment: It is called [Promise Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining), the `then()` also returns a new `Promise`, and return values from previous `then` are passed to the next `then`.